# Custom alert view in iOS issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview

In my app I've to create a custom alert view like the following:

[image]

So I followed this [tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-sdk-creating-a-custom-alert-view--mobile-16842) to create a custom alert view. I finished it but I'm getting issue in the following method:

```
- (void)addOrRemoveButtonWithTag:(int)tag andActionToPerform:(BOOL)shouldRemove {
    NSMutableArray *items = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    [items addObject:self.buttonOk];
    [items addObject:self.buttonClose];

    int buttonIndex = (tag == 1);

    if (shouldRemove) {
        [items removeObjectAtIndex:buttonIndex];
    } else {
        if (tag == 1) {
            [items insertObject:self.buttonOk atIndex:buttonIndex];
        } else {
            [items insertObject:self.buttonClose atIndex:buttonIndex];
        }
    }
}
```

I edited it than the tutorial because I don't need a UIToolBar for buttons. When I run the app it says me that I can't insert a nil object in an NSMutableArray, but I don't understand what's wrong, I hope you can help me to fix this issue.

**UPDATE**
Here's all the class code I developed:

```
#import "CustomAlertViewController.h"

#define ANIMATION_DURATION  0.25

@interface CustomAlertViewController ()
- (IBAction)buttonOk:(UIButton *)sender;
- (IBAction)buttonCancel:(UIButton *)sender;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *buttonClose;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *buttonOk;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *viewAlert;

-(void)addOrRemoveButtonWithTag:(int)tag andActionToPerform:(BOOL)shouldRemove;

@end

@implementation CustomAlertViewController

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        [self.viewAlert setFrame:CGRectMake(self.labelAlertView.frame.origin.x,
                                         self.labelAlertView.frame.origin.y,
                                         self.labelAlertView.frame.size.width,
                                         self.viewAlert.frame.size.height)];
        [self.buttonOk setTag:1];
        [self.buttonClose setTag:0];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)showCustomAlertInView:(UIView *)targetView withMessage:(NSString *)message {
    CGFloat statusBarOffset;

    if (![[UIApplication sharedApplication] isStatusBarHidden]) {
        CGSize statusBarSize = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarFrame].size;
        if (statusBarSize.width < statusBarSize.height) {
            statusBarOffset = statusBarSize.width;
        } else {
            statusBarOffset = statusBarSize.height;
        }
    } else {
        statusBarOffset = 0.0;
    }
    CGFloat width, height, offsetX, offsetY;

    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation] == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft ||
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation] == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
        width = targetView.frame.size.width;
        height = targetView.frame.size.height;

        offsetX = 0.0;
        offsetY = -statusBarOffset;
    }

    [self.view setFrame:CGRectMake(targetView.frame.origin.x, targetView.frame.origin.y, width, height)];
    [self.view setFrame:CGRectOffset(self.view.frame, offsetX, offsetY)];
    [targetView addSubview:self.view];

    [self.viewAlert setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, -self.viewAlert.frame.size.height, self.viewAlert.frame.size.width, self.viewAlert.frame.size.height)];

    [UIView beginAnimations:@"" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:ANIMATION_DURATION];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];
    [self.viewAlert setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, self.viewAlert.frame.size.width, self.viewAlert.frame.size.height)];
    [UIView commitAnimations];

    [self.labelAlertView setText:@"CIAO"];
}

- (void)removeCustomAlertFromView {
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:ANIMATION_DURATION];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];
    [self.viewAlert setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, -self.viewAlert.frame.size.height, self.viewAlert.frame.size.width, self.viewAlert.frame.size.height)];
    [UIView commitAnimations];

    [self.view performSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview) withObject:nil afterDelay:ANIMATION_DURATION];
}

- (void)removeCustomAlertFromViewInstantly {
    [self.view removeFromSuperview];
}

- (BOOL)isOkayButtonRemoved {
    if (self.buttonOk == nil) {
        return YES;
    } else {
        return NO;
    }
}

- (BOOL)isCancelButtonRemoved {
    if (self.buttonClose == nil) {
        return YES;
    } else {
        return NO;
    }
}

- (void)removeOkayButton:(BOOL)shouldRemove {
    if ([self isOkayButtonRemoved] != shouldRemove) {
        [self addOrRemoveButtonWithTag:1 andActionToPerform:shouldRemove];
    }
}

- (void)removeCancelButton:(BOOL)shouldRemove {
    if ([self isCancelButtonRemoved] != shouldRemove) {
        [self addOrRemoveButtonWithTag:0 andActionToPerform:shouldRemove];
    }
}

- (void)addOrRemoveButtonWithTag:(int)tag andActionToPerform:(BOOL)shouldRemove {
    NSMutableArray *items = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    [items addObject:self.buttonOk];
    [items addObject:self.buttonClose];

    int buttonIndex = (tag == 1);

    if (shouldRemove) {
        [items removeObjectAtIndex:buttonIndex];
    } else {
        if (tag == 1) {
            [items insertObject:self.buttonOk atIndex:buttonIndex];
        } else {
            [items insertObject:self.buttonClose atIndex:buttonIndex];
        }
    }
}

- (IBAction)buttonOk:(UIButton *)sender {
    [self.delegate customAlertOk];
}

- (IBAction)buttonCancel:(UIButton *)sender {
    [self.delegate customAlertCancel];
}
@end
```

**UPDATE 2**
Code in which I use the CustomAlertView:

```
#import "PromotionsViewController.h"
#import "CustomAlertViewController.h"

@interface PromotionsViewController () <CustomAlertViewControllerDelegate> {
    BOOL isDeletingItem;
}


@property(nonatomic,strong) CustomAlertViewController *customAlert;

- (IBAction)buttonBack:(UIButton *)sender;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *buttonAlert;
- (IBAction)buttonAlert:(UIButton *)sender;

@end

@implementation PromotionsViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    [self.buttonAlert setTitle:self.promotionSelected forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.customAlert setDelegate:self];
    isDeletingItem = NO;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)buttonBack:(UIButton *)sender {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
- (IBAction)buttonAlert:(UIButton *)sender {
    self.customAlert = [[CustomAlertViewController alloc]init];
    [self.customAlert removeOkayButton:NO];
    [self.customAlert removeCancelButton:NO];
    NSString *message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"La tua offerta %@ del 20%% è stata convertita in punti IoSi x10", self.promotionSelected];
    [self.customAlert showCustomAlertInView:self.view withMessage:message];
    isDeletingItem = YES;
}

- (void)customAlertOk {
    if (isDeletingItem) {
        [self.customAlert removeCustomAlertFromViewInstantly];
    } else {
        [self.customAlert removeCustomAlertFromView];
    }
}

- (void)customAlertCancel {
    [self.customAlert removeCustomAlertFromView];
    if (isDeletingItem) {
        isDeletingItem = NO;
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: How are you initializing your two buttons ?

Comment: I just followed the tutorial, I designed the 2 button by using Interface Builder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you're calling `addOrRemoveButtonWithTag:andActionToPerform:` at a time where your UI is not fully created, since UI elements are created asynchronously. So if you call this method, right after custom alert view instanciation, you'll get your crash because the buttons in the view are not created.

To solve this issue, you need to call  `addOrRemoveButtonWithTag:andActionToPerform:`  only once your custom alert has been added to the view hierarchy.

***EDIT :***

With the example code you gave in edit 2, you call these lines :

```
- (IBAction)buttonAlert:(UIButton *)sender {
  self.customAlert = [[CustomAlertViewController alloc]init];
  [self.customAlert removeOkayButton:NO];
  [self.customAlert removeCancelButton:NO];
}
```

but when you have just instantiated `CustomAlertViewController`, its 2 buttons are not yet created, so I suggest you add 2 properties `hasOkButton` and `hasCancelButton` and a new constructor to your custom class like this one :

```
- (instancetype) initWithOk:(BOOL)OkButton AndCancel:(BOOL) CancelButton
{
    if(self = [super init])
    { 
       hasOkButton = OkButton;
       hasCancelButton = CancelButton;
    }
}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
      [super viewWillAppear:animated];
      // At this time, the custom UI buttons will be created in the UI view hierarchy
      [self removeOkayButton: hasOkButton];
      [self removeOkayButton: hasCancelButton];
}
```

And in the caller you can use the following to display a custom alert View:

```
- (IBAction)buttonAlert:(UIButton *)sender {
    self.customAlert = [[CustomAlertViewController alloc] initWithOk:NO AndCancel:NO];
    // ...
}
```

***EDIT #2***

I tried your solution in a real project, I made it work by using these lines  int the caller :

```
- (IBAction)buttonAlert:(UIButton *)sender {
    self.customAlert = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"customAlertView"];
    self.customAlert.hasOK = NO;
    self.customAlert.hasCancel = YES;
    NSString *message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"La tua offerta %@ del 20%% è stata convertita in punti IoSi x10", self.promotionSelected];
    [self.customAlert showCustomAlertInView:self.view withMessage:message];
    isDeletingItem = YES;
}
```

In the `CustomAlertViewController` declare 2 visible properties `hasOK` and `hasCancel` in.h.
And modify your .m by adding method :

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self removeOkayButton:self.hasOK];
    [self removeCancelButton:self.hasCancel];
}
```

Be sure to modify your storyboard (if eligible) to have the "customAlertView" defined this way :

[image: Screen capture of storyboard properties]

Don't forget also to bind your UIButton to the controller this can be a mistake too in your implementation :

[image: Bind UIButtons to the controller]

Hope this will help you :)

Comment: I just added all the code I insert in my `CustomAlertViewController.m`, I hope you can help me to find out where's my error

Comment: @lucgian841 Can you add the code in which you insert a new CustomAlertViewController ? I think you're just calling the method addOrRemoveButtonWithTag:andActionToPerform: too soon... causing your crash

Comment: I update my question by adding the code in which I'm calling the CustomAlertView

Comment: I tested your code in a new Xcode project, it seems your custom alert view controller is not linked to any UI element (XIB or storyboard). I'll add some code to link to a storyboard definition.

Comment: Thank you! With your suggest now it goes not so good but it's working, now I've to fix other stuff

Answer (score 0):

I found on the web a tutorial to create custom alert view by using code, if you are interested you can go to this [tutorial](http://iosdevtricks.blogspot.it/2013/04/creating-custom-alert-view-for-iphone.html). I used it for my issue and it worked great! You have to fix a few things, because it uses deprecated command but it's easy to fix it.
If you are interested just take a look about this tutorial. I think you can integrate it in your app and after you can easily use for other stuff if it's necessary. I hope that my answer will help someone.